# execute batch script from a remote computer

Tags: windows, batch-file

Computer A is on network and is our main server. Currently, we have a windows batch script which is stored in c:\scripts folder. This batch script accepts 2 string parameters (eg. TEST ABCD)

Currently, I go to this server, fireup the command prompt and then execute the script. eg:

```
script.bat TEST ABCD
```

I want to execute this script over the LAN from ANY computer. What is the best way to call the batch script on server A from any computer?

I have never tried this, so have little to no clue. I tried searching stackOverflow, but, did not get any concrete answers. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the folder  c:\scripts on computer A with the other computers?

Comment: @zdan yes, i think that can be done. if yes, how will it work?

Comment: As I understand it he wants the script to run on the server, not on the client.

Comment: What Windows versions are you using? All of the modern versions (XP and up for desktop, Win2003 for server, IIRC) support *Remote Desktop* or RDP (previously named *Terminal Server*). This gives you access to the remote computer just like you were sitting at it. (If you need more info about RDP, start at [Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/connect-using-remote-desktop-connection#connect-using-remote-desktop-connection=windows-7). If you have questions after that, you should ask them on [su] instead, as that isn't a programming topic and thus isn't on-topic here.)

Comment: Unfortunately RDP isn't an alternative.

Comment: I can probably use powershell, if that is an option to call the script remotely....

Answer (score 0):

You could use Telnet. Windows has [built-in telnet server support](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754837%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and a [telnet client](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771275%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

You would set up the telnet server on the server and log in from the client. This will be much like a command prompt would be on the server.

**Update:**

Another alternative would be to set up a web server (IIS is built-in in windows, but any web server will do) and set up a CGI script that will run your batch file. You could even have a page that lets your team enter/change the parameters to the script.

I think the details to this CGI script are worth a followup question though.

Comment: will it mean opening up a port in the firewall on the server? Also, would I need to create a new user on the server to login via telnet?

Comment: @MonilChheda If you have a 3rd party FW then probably yes, I think the Windows FW will have its port opened. You can create a dedicated user if you like but it should work with your current user as well.

Comment: I am just a bit worried that not all people in my team are so technically savvy to login to a server using telnet. I was looking at more of a simple syntax to call the batch script.

Comment: @MonilChheda In that case maybe you can use a web server with a CGI script.

Comment: Just curious how would that work... May be I am overthinking... Doesn't windows have any utility/ commands which can call a remote script and execute it there with a simple command?

Comment: @MonilChheda That's Telnet. As for the script, it's just a script that would call the batch file and show the result embedded in a HTML page. I don't know ASP so if you ask me I'd tell you to install Perl and write a script with that. Someone who knows ASP might be able to help you with a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have read/write access to the server:

```
pushd "\\server\batch file folder\"
script.bat TEST ABCD
popd
```

Comment: Can you please share some details of what these commands will do? I read the description but wasn't clear on its working

Comment: Type `HELP PUSHD` and `HELP POPD`

Comment: with this command, will the script execute locally or remote computer where the script is hosted?

Comment: It will execute on the local CPU but process the files on the remote computer, depending on what the batch file does.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done from command prompt or bat file wmic /node:MachineName> process call create "cmd.exe c:\Test\script.bat TEST ABCD"

For help wmic /?